# fibonacci sequence using vector

Tags: c++

I have to code the following fibonacci but I want to do it with a vector to show my teacher that I'm getting away from all the lesson, but I have several warning like this:

```
main.cpp: 18: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness:
    'int' to 'std::vector::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')

main.cpp: 18: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness:
    'int' to 'std::vector::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')
```

and I do not understand why it does not work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> table;
    table[0] = 0;
    table[1] = 1;

    if (n == 0) { cout << n << endl; }
    else if (n == 1) { cout << n << endl; }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            table[i] = table[i - 1] + table[i - 2];
            cout << table[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These warnings are unrelated to the problem in your code. Your problem is that `table` is empty. It has 0 elements. It can store 0 elements inside. So when you do `table[0]`, you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and what do I have to do to fix the problem?

Comment: @martingenereux Your code has _undefined behavior_. Use `push_back()` to add elements to the vector before accessing specific indexes with the indexing `operator[]()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has already been pointed out by "Yksisarvinem" in the question comments, so I'll just provide the corrected code here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> table;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
            table.push_back(n);
            cout << n << endl;
            continue;
        }
        table.push_back(table[i - 1] + table[i - 2]);
        cout << table[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it work now and why do I still get the same warnings when I try to compile your code?

Comment: @Swordfish I'm unable to run the code rn, but it should work. The issues mentioned by "Yksisarvinem" and "Quimby" have both been handled appropriately. Can you elaborate as to what warning you're getting exactly?

Comment: Look at the compiler messages in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Vector's indexing operator has signature `T& operator[](std::size_t i)` and you are indexing using `int` variable.

You should use `std::size_t i` in the for loop because indices are always non-negative.

But this warning was quite useful in this case because you have a bug in your code. On the first iteration when `i=0` the `table[i-1] + table[i-2]` expression evaluates to `table[-1] + table[-2]`. Which is not what you want. Had you used `std::size_t i` the index would underflow to a big number and you would have a index out of bounds.

The solution is to manually set `tabular[0],tabular[1]`, start with `std::size_t i=2` and you might want to add `table.resize(n);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to change the elements of your vector but your vector is actually empty.

You can do two things

1. When you declare your vector do `vector<int> table(n);` in this way you are telling it has `n` uninitialized elements and so later you can reassign their value.
2. alternatively append your new elements to the vector:

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       int n;
       cin >> n;

       vector<int> table;
       table.push_back(0);
       table.push_back(1);

       if (n == 0) {
           cout << n << endl;
       }
       else if (n == 1) {
           cout << n << endl;
       }
       else {
           for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
               table.push_back(table[i - 1] + table[i - 2]);
               cout << table[i];
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that in the `for` it does not make sense to start from `0` as index: start directly from 2.

**EDIT**
You problem might be that if you input a big number at a certain point Fibonacci's values might exceed the maximum value an `int` can store.

First of all since you are dealing with positive number to expand the range use always `unsigned`. Try to define your vector as `vector<unsigned long int> table;` or `vector<unsigned long long int> table;`.

For even bigger values you can use external libraries.

Comment: Why do I still get the same warnings when I try to compile your code?

Comment: In both the solutions? Which number have inputted? Maybe if the number is too big so instead of a vector  of `int` you should use something more such as `unsigned int` `unsigned long int`

Comment: Read the compiler messages in the question.

Comment: I read it. From the warning seems to tell that it is automatically casting from int to unsigned long. Again: what input did you use? Without it it is difficult to reproduce the problem. Note that the accepted answer comes from this comment `These warnings are unrelated to the problem in your code. Your problem is that table is empty. It has 0 elements. It can store 0 elements inside. So when you do table[0], you have Undefined Behaviour.` which is exactly what I was trying to tell.

Comment: *I read it. From the warning seems to tell that it is automatically casting from int to unsigned long.* – Then fix it? A newline after each Fibonacci number would be nice too.

Comment: Listen: I took the code from the question. I don't understand what you are asking either.

Comment: I'm not asking anything. You see the warnings? If you don't get them compile with `-Wconversion`.

Comment: DId you read the accepted answer? It is saying exactly what I am telling in mine

Comment: I didn't say that the accepted answer is any better.

Comment: If it's accepted it means it solved the problem of the asker